# Microsoft Word equivalent of CSS "clear" property?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, graphics

The [`clear` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/clear) in CSS can be used to ensure that a new paragraph begins after (below) a floating image. Is there a way to do this in Microsoft Word 2010? (I'm able to position a graphic to the right of the text in a paragraph, but I'd like the next section to begin below the graphic, rather than wrapping around it.)

Answer (score 10):

Insert a Text wrapping break on the line you want to keep below the floating image.

1. Click where the text wrapping break is to be inserted
2. Click the Page Layout Tab
3. In the Page Setup Area, from the Breaks dropdown, select Text Wrapping

[image: Text Wrapping break screenshot]

> A text wrapping break ends the current line and forces the text to
>   continue below a picture, table, or other item. The text continues on
>   the next blank line that doesn't contain a picture or table aligned
>   with the left or right margin.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255521

Comment: *This* was exactly what I needed to have two separate sections on a page, each with their own graphic - Continuous Section Break + Text Wrapping Break. It's so hard to search for, since Word doesn't use the same language for this as CSS/Web.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the image then highlight **Wrap Text** then choose which one you want. I believe you would want **Top and Bottom**.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified I'm using Office 2010. There is no Wrap Text option when I right click.

Comment: Ok, then click the image then go to the **Format** tab. There should be a **Wrap Text** button there.

Comment: No, that's not it. You want the wrapping to be 'Square' or 'Tight', but only up to some point.